# How to pass values from one test to another in Munit4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, munit

I have 2 testcases.
One test case, tests the authentication and gets  token info in the header. I want to store it and use it in another testcase.
I tried store processor at 1st teastcase and tried retrieving it from 2nd testcase. But it says `"couldnot find the key`." Is this approach wrong?
Also, I tried queue /dequeue option. In this case i got,

```
Time out waiting for queue to return a result.
```

How to achieve this simple case?

Comment: could you please share your flows or more details. Generally all the flow receives payload and flowvars from previous flow ( that can be mocked )

Answer (score 0):

Authentication should be mocked on all the other methods since you'll be testing the functionality and not the actual response from the server.

Take a look to this link:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.2/mock-event-processor